# What does this code with "?" and "??" mean?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, syntax, operators

What does this syntax mean? I'm currently coding c# 4.0, when I came by this piece of code.

```
_data = (SerializationHelper.Deserialize(Request.Form[_dataKey])
             ? TempData[_dataKey] ?? new ProfileData ()) as ProfileData;
```

If I were to write it i IF statements how would it be then?

The compiler gives me an error for not writing a : aswell as more things are needed?

Comment: @pst I did! But as you see the code was faulty so i thought there was something special going on.. But youre right I should have written that..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you missed a `?` there.  I suspect it was supposed to read:

```
_data = (SerializationHelper.Deserialize(Request.Form[_dataKey])
            ?? TempData[_dataKey]
            ?? new ProfileData()
        ) as ProfileData;
```

In C# the operation `A ?? B` is directly equivalent to `(A == null ? B : A)`, or `if (A == null) return B; return A;` if you prefer.

So your statement above is equivalent to:

```
object tmp = SerializationHelper.Deserialize(Request.Form[_dataKey]);
if (tmp == null)
{
    tmp = TempData[_dataKey];
    if (tmp == null)
        _tmp = new ProfileData();
}
_data = tmp as ProfileData;
```

Answer (score 4):

?? means if it's null, use the other value. For example

```
var name = somevalue ?? "Default Name";
```

If `somevalue` is null, it will assign the value "Default Name"

Also the single ? is a ternary operator, basically you use it like this:

```
var example = (conditional statement here) ? value_if_true : value_if_false;
```

However your code doesn't seem to follow the right syntax for ternary operators when I look at it properly, as Corey says, you may have missed a ? off a ??.